# How to replace a button in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am displaying some records table where each row contains two buttons like

"Accept" and "Reject"

If I click on "Accept" then the form should be submitted and the button should Replace with "Cancel" button and page should reload with fresh content in the table.

And If I click on "Reject" button then "Accept" button should hide And page should reload with fresh content.

I have tried something but did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#upComing").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
      });
      $("#btnAccept").click(function(){
          $("form[value='Accept${upComLeave.employee_id}']").submit();
          location.replace("#btnCancel");

      });  
    });
```

please help me.

Comment: Hide `btnAccept` and show `btnCancel`, using `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: I did try but did not work because the form is getting submit and not going further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have three buttons, Accept, Cancel (hidden at first) and Reject and show and hide them to achieve what you describe:

```
$('#btAccept').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#btCancel').show(); 
    //submit form
});

$('#btCancel').click(function(){
    //cancel ajax request
    return false; //prevent form from submitting
});

$('#btReject').click(function(){    
    $('#btAccept').hide(); 
    //refresh content
    return false; //prevent form from submitting
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/86w5K/) that shows it working.

Comment: I tried your solution and the button is getting replaced but if I refresh the page then form is submitting twice i.e.duplicate submit

Comment: how to restrict that?

Comment: @user3448105 if you don't want the button to automatically submit the form you can return false from the handler. I'll update the answer. Also, you might want to check the section "The event handler and its environment" [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I got your answer.I have been trying on duplicate form submition in spring and jquery however,have not succeed.

Comment: I want the button to submit the form But,When we refresh the page then it should not submit twice right?